# Custom SQL In Product Grid

Tags: php, sql, magento, zend-framework2, magento-1.9

How can I add a custom SQL call in the product grid.

This is what I have so far:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('attribute_set_id')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('type_id');

$collection->joinField(
            'quantity_in_stock',
            'advancedinventory',
            'quantity_in_stock',
            'product_id=entity_id',
            'advancedinventory.place_id=1',
            'inner'
        );

$this->addColumn('quantity_in_stock',
        array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Custom Column'),
            'width' => '80px',
            'type' => 'number',
            'index' => 'quantity_in_stock'
    ));
```

but this doesn't seem to work, I need to get the value from the table `advancedinventory` where `product_id` is the id of that entity and `place_id` is always equal to 1.

Could anyone provide any help at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it,

To fix it I had to make the collection this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('attribute_set_id')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('type_id')
            ->joinField('quantity_in_stock', 'mage_advancedinventory', 'quantity_in_stock', 'product_id=entity_id', 'place_id=1', 'left');`

$this->addColumn('quantity_in_stock',
     array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Custom Column'),
            'width' => '80px',
            'type' => 'number',
            'index' => 'quantity_in_stock'
     )
);
```

Comment: Is it really necessary to join the field twice as the second join seemed to not work previously ?

Comment: Probably not actually. I will amend the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like below

here is simple example which you can apply to your collection

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')

                    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('price')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('status')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('visibility')
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'simple'))
                    ->addFieldToFilter('status', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array('neq' => 1));


   $collection->getSelect()->join(array('abvinv' => "advancedinventory"), "e.entity_id = abvinv.product_id", array('abvinv.*'))
```

here i am assuming that `product_id` column which is available in `advancedinventory` table

Hope this will sure work for you.

Comment: Hi, I've tried that and it just makes the product grid page freeze. I am about to edit the main question to add more information.

Comment: that means you have to write left join with your custom table ?

Comment: Sorry, where do I have to add the left join on the `advancedinventory` table within the collection? Could you please amend your answer to show me?

Answer (score 0):

The name of the table should be as defined for the magento getResourceModel. eg : catalog/category, directory/country_name...

If it does not work, you can still try to edit the select with $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(...).